# how to send data from a function out GUI matlab to function GUI.m

Tags: matlab, user-interface

How can I pass values (x_locate, y_locate) for a static text in my GUI? 
Because the function is out functions generated by the GUI. I'm not achieving to configure the set() function.

I believe it is using handles, but I've tried everything and failed.

to simplify I rewrote the code:
![enter image description here][1]

The "Locations.fig" have: 1 axes, 1 pushbutton and 2 static text.

ctrl+C

```
function varargout = Locations(varargin)
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Locations_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Locations_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end
if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end

function Locations_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;
guidata(hObject, handles);

function varargout = Locations_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
varargout{1} = handles.output;

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
axes(handles.axes1);

image = imread('eight.tif');
im = imagesc(image);

set(im,'ButtonDownFcn', @clique);

function clique (gcbo,eventdata,handles)

pos = get(gca, 'currentpoint');

x_locate = round(pos(1))
y_locate = round(pos(3))  % until here working!!!

set(handles.text1, 'string', ['x loc:' num2str(x_locate)]); %don´t working
set(handles.text2, 'string', ['y loc:' num2str(y_locate)]); %don´t working
```

Comment: Try declaring the handle to the static text as a global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only callbacks set through GUIDE (or some other custom means) receive the extra `handles` argument. Otherwise, you'll need to [retrieve the handles structure manually](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) within the `clique` function:

```
handles = guidata(<object>);
```

The question of what `<object>` is depends on your GUI setup. If `im` is a child of the GUI figure, then `gcbo`<sup>1</sup> will do. If it's in a separate figure, then you'll need to get a handle to the GUI figure. Using [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to either enumerate all figures or search for some specific property of your GUI figure is the straightforward way to do it.

For example, all Handle Graphics objects have a `'Tag'` property that you are free to use, which would be helpful in this case. In GUIDE, set the `Tag` property on your GUI figure to `'my GUI'`, then you can retrieve the data from anywhere like so:

```
hfig = findobj('Tag','my GUI');
handles = guidata(hfig);
```

[1] Incidentally, giving variables the same name as built-in functions isn't a great idea

Comment: humm!!! That's what I was trying to do but could not. I still do not dominate very well ... Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ButtonDownFcn` to be:

```
set(im, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(src,evt)clique(src,evt,handles))
```

Comment: Thank you Kavka. Your tip works in substitution: set(im,'ButtonDownFcn', @clique);  But don't send to static text in GUI the values x_locate and y_locate.

Answer (score 0):

The Notlikethat resolved the problem! Thanks!!!

so:

```
x_locate = round(pos(1));
y_locate = round(pos(3));  % until here working!!!

hfig1 = findobj('Tag','text1');
handles = guidata(hfig1);
hfig2 = findobj('tag','text2');
handles = guidata(hfig2);

set(handles.text1, 'string', ['x loc:' num2str(x_locate)]);
set(handles.text2, 'string', ['y loc:' num2str(y_locate)]);
```

***finalized***